# Fetch and post text in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I'm trying to grab text from an API that only returns a string of text ([(here)](http://taskinoz.com/gdq/api)) and having troubles throwing that out in a response. When posting, it comes out as `[object Response]`, and the `console.log` doesn't show the text I want out of it.

The code I'm using:

```
fetch('http://taskinoz.com/gdq/api').then(
    function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      throttledSendMessage(channel, response);
      return response;
    })
  .catch(function(error) {
    throttledSendMessage(channel, "An error has occured");
  })
```

Log can be [found here](https://pastebin.com/z76DVZbM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the problem is in async behavior of node.js. You can read more [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) 

Also, I'm assume you use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) package to make fetch request in node.js.
And assume that `throttledSendMessage` function is synchronous.

About your problem, just try to rewrite co de to use async/await for cleaner solution.

```
// We'll use IIFE function
(async () => {
    const fetchResult = await fetch('http://taskinoz.com/gdq/api')
    // Here fetch return the promise, so we need to await it again and parse according to our needs. So, the result code would be this
    const data = await fetchResult.text();
    throttledSendMessage(channel, data);
    return data;
})()
```

Comment: The answer to this question has absolutely nothing to do with async behaviour in Node and everything to do with the fact `fetch` returns a response object and not the raw response data.

Comment: fetch is not natively supported by nodejs. The above code will work in a modern browser, and will work in node if it's been polyfilled, but there is no native fetch. Check [node.green](http://node.green) for a list of compatible language features and the node documentation for native APIs.

Comment: @FishPudding, please, read my answer attentively. I've mentioned about package, required to run this code. With link to npm package.

Comment: The previous comment is out of date. **[Fetch has been included in node since version 18](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v18-release-announce)**

Answer (score 6):

I think that because `fetch` returns a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) you need to call one of the functions on `Response` in order to get at the body's text. Here's an example:

```
fetch('https://github.com/')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(body => console.log(body));
```

Answer (score 2):

`Fetch` is not available in nodejs , you could use the `node-fetch` https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch , or you could use this `fetch` function:

```
const https = require('https');
const http = require('http');

function fetch(url, options = {}) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!url) return reject(new Error('Url is required'));

    const { body, method = 'GET', ...restOptions } = options;
    const client = url.startsWith('https') ? https : http;

    const request = client.request(url, { method, ...restOptions }, (res) => {
      let chunks = '';

      res.setEncoding('utf8');

      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        chunks += chunk;
      });

      res.on('end', () => {
        resolve({ statusCode: res.statusCode, body: chunks });
      });
    });

    request.on('error', (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });

    if (body) {
      request.setHeader('Content-Length', body.length);
      request.write(body);
    }

    request.end();
  });
}

module.exports = fetch;
```

you could use it like this inside your code :

```
  const result = await fetch(
    `https://YOUR_URL`,
    {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify({ test: 'This is just a test', prio: 1 }),
    },
  );
```