# how to read json file on our folder and put it on html

Tags: javascript, json

I have json fil on my folder and I already install http-serve also to run locally but nothing show on my console chrome to fetch json data, any idea ??

here is my javascript to call it and show on my html and developers tool

```
  async function bestFetch() {
      try {
         const first = fetch('./data.json');
         let json = await first_name.json();
         console.log(first);
       }
       catch(e) {
         console.log('Error!', e);
       }
      }
```

Comment: Is this Nodejs?

Comment: this maybe help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070032/fetch-and-post-text-in-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

The `fetch` function is asynchronous, which means that the code doesn't wait for it to finish fetching before moving on to the next line. With this in mind, make sure your code waits for the fetch, before getting the json and logging it to the console:

```
async function bestFetch() {
  try {
     const first = await fetch('./data.json'); //<-- wait for the fetch to finish and return the resolved value. 
     let json = await first.json(); //<-- use the const first, not first_name
     console.log(first);
   }
   catch(e) {
     console.log('Error!', e);
   }
  }
```

Comment: I tried that, but still can't show it on my console.log develovers tool

Comment: @poppop Are you sture data.json is a correct data file and is being fetched?

Answer (score 0):

If you file is in the same path of your HTML file, you can call "./data.json" and when to fetch return a promise, it needs to convert to json and convert your response and add into you HTML selecting your element "demo" and add into .innerHTml.

```
    fetch('./data.json').then(response => {
      return response.json();
    }).then(data => {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data;
      console.log(data);
    }).catch(err => {
      // Do something for an error here
    });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp

Comment: I tried that, but still can't show it on my console.log develovers tool

Comment: did you try use alert instead console.log, only to be sure you are getting the data? like alert(data);